# Better way to replace nested if else in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Is there any better way to replace below if else to more cleaner in Kotlin. I tried to replace with when statement but i couldn't match the logic.

```
if (!reached)
        {
            if (!info)
            {
                d.sinfo = extractinfo()
            }
            else
            {
                parserMessage("print something")
                return d
            }
            info = true
        }
        else
        {
            if (d.media.isEmpty()){
                parserMessage("print something")
                return d
            }
            else{
                if (d.media.at(d.media.size() - 1).media_information.isEmpty())
                    {d.media[d.media.size() - 1].minfo = extractinfo()}
                else{
                    parserMessage("print something")
                    return d

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems like this bit of the code has many responsibilities. If you could split it into some smaller, more focused functions, the code overall would be less messy. It would help to have an explanation of what `d`, `reached`, and `info` refer to and the context of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the code you have left out have some weird side effects, this code *should* be semantically equal:

```
when {
    !reached && !info -> {
        d.sinfo = extractinfo()
        info = true
    }
    !reached && info -> {
        parserMessage("print something")
        return d
    }
    d.media.isEmpty() -> {
        parserMessage("print something")
        return d
    }
    d.media.at(d.media.size() - 1).media_information.isEmpty() -> {
        d.media[d.media.size() - 1].minfo = extractinfo()
    }
    else -> {
        parserMessage("print something")
        return d
    }
}
```

However, to say this, I had to fill in the gaps in the code you have presented myself, so I can't state this very confidently. It really helps your chances of getting a good answer if the code you want help with is runnable/understandable as presented.

By the way. This refactoring was partly done by pasting the code into IntelliJ and hitting Alt+Enter and choosing "Replace 'if' with 'when'" and "Flatten when"